# how to show a Custom Dialog Box with animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to show a Custom dialoge box like this on pressing a button in flutter, is there is any package or widgets that can archive this??
[image: something similar this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the best method for a widget like this (Custom dialog box)this will give you a good scale transition and you can set any widget as a custom dialog box.

```
showGeneralDialog(
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: a1.value,
        //here inside opacity define your child instead projectdetails()
        child: Opacity(opacity: a1.value, child: ProjectDetails()),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: '',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
    //return a emty container 
      return Container();

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no package as such that you need to the best of my knowledge.

You'll have to `make` this a `custom widget` make sure the `root of the widget is StatefulBuilder` so that you can have your carousel work as desired.

And then simply call

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => WidgetYouMade()
);
```